# Call React Component Method in Backbone Controller/class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, backbone.js, callback

I'm working on a project build with Backbone JS, we are using an architecture az describes We have Models, View, and Controllers that connect them.

We started creating some React components recently and I had a task to remake a Handlebars + JQ Form to React Form.

So I did it but now I have this problem: I need to have a way to get the state of the Form Components, which contains the data.

Until now in the handlebars + JQ form we had a

> _getFormData() { return jq_formData; }

method that simply used JQ to extract the data, but since now the form is in React, it's not good to use JQ again.

The Form will be initialized  with

in react:

```
class Form extends Component {
   state = {}

   getFormData() { return this.state; }

   updateFormData (e) { this.setState({ [e.name]: e.value }) }

   render() { return ( ... Child InputsFields update={this.updateFormData} ...) }  

}
```

in backbone:

```
 class View {
    $el = $('#formContainer'),

    // my idea is to have something like this 
    _getFormData(){
       return Form.getFormData() 
    }
    render () {
       ReactDOM.render(<Form {...formData} />, this.$el[0])
    }
 }
```

So later I can use the View Instance in the Controller as this:

```
class Controler {
   this.view = new View();

   this.formData = this.view._getFormData(); // { name: 'tony', age: 34 }
}
```

I also taught about using

> React.createRef()

but i'm not sure how this needs to be implemented with

> ReactDOM.render( form, $el)

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for a ref, `ReactDOM.render` already returns a ref for rendered component:

```
this.instance = ReactDOM.render(<Form {...formData} />, this.$el[0]);
```

So it can be accessed later as `this.instance.getFormData()`. Also, component state is public and doesn't need `getFormData` getter, it can be retrieved with `this.instance.state`.